# On click function appears to be active after element removal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a program that finds the shortest path in a graph, this program is created on click by appending divs to a container. The main program appears to work as intended, the problem arises when I remove the program and start it again. The functions appear to execute 2 times.

You can see the problem on http://runaider.github.io/ just click "Path Finder" then create some vertexes, click "Path Finder" again and try to create vertexes again you'll see the problem.

I tried using .remove(), .unbind(), .cleanData() but nothing helps.

This is one of the functions that i spoke of

```
$(document).on ("click", "#B1", function () {
    count++;
    alert(count);
    $('.MainField').append(
        $('<div class="Vertex">').attr("id","V"+count).text("V"+count)
    );
    jsPlumb.draggable('V'+count, {containment:"parent"})
});
```

This is how i remove the the objects:

```
function DispandGraphField(){
jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
$('.MainField').animate({opacity:0},1000,function(){});
$('.Options').animate({opacity:0},1000,function(){
    $('.Graph').animate({width:1,height:1,borderRadius:180},700,function(){
        $('#B1').unbind();
        $('.OptionsSec1').empty();
        $('.OptionsSec2').empty();
        $('.Options').empty();
        $('.Graph').remove();
    });
});
```

If you need to see all the code look here https://github.com/Runaider/Runaider.github.io (script.js and GraphScript.js)

I have probably made some stupid mistakes and would appreciate your help in finding and solving them.

Comment: You are bind the event on the document, you need to remove it from the document, not `#b1`.

Comment: First, you need to reset the `count` variable when removing the div. Then, your `unbind` is on `#B1`, but you bound it to `document`. So instead of `.on('click'`, you could use `.bind('click'`, and remove it by doing `$(document).unbind("click", "#B1");`.

Comment: $(document).off("click", "#B1", false); should work too.

Comment: @blex Thx, your answer was helpful. But my problem actually was in my function declaration the code snippets that i posted here didn't show where the problem really lays.